# Grouping threads for interruption

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I'm facing some problem with thread grouping and it's an interruption (canceling some continuous process). I have one point of execution entry managed by `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and that works with `@Async` annotation on method. After an asynchronous invocation and run of this method, inside it I have some another async work to be completed by some `new Thread()`. Consider that I could have a situation when I have some those tasks running in parallel I need to identify and what task is it and `interrupt()` given **task** and it **child threads**  that created during task execution.

I've investigated already some things about this problem. I could set some `ThreadGroup` for `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`, get this group and `interrupt()` it. This could stop running task and threads created during task execution, but I need something like **dynamic** `ThreadGroup` depending on the task id, for not to stopping other running tasks, because setting `ThreadGroup` through `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor().setThreadGroup()` sets all Executor's tasks given group.
Accessing `Future<>` of the created task and invoking `future.cancel()` helps to stop current task, but not **child** threads

```java
    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("thread-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
```

```java
    public class Task {
       private Long id;
       //getters and setters
    }
```

```java
   @Service
    public class AsyncService {

        @Async("taskExecutor")
        public Future<Task> startAsyncProcess(Task task){
            //this thread is not killed by future.cancel()
            new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Some continuous async db write")).start();
            //Some other continuous process, killed by future.cancel()
            return AsyncResult.forValue(task);
        }

    }
```

```java
    @Service
    public class TaskService {

        @Autowired
        private AsyncService asyncService;

        public void startProcess(Task task){
          Future<Task> future = asyncService.startAsyncProcess(task);
          // future.cancel();
        }

    }
```

I expect to make some complete interrupt of those threads. Maybe I need to create some manager for this and use `ThreadFactory` to generate those threads and separate them into small groups using `ThreadGroup`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty but it works: implement a type like `CancelWithRunnableFuture` which you can provide a `Runnable` to... That `Runnable` is called inside the `cancel()` method.

```
@Service
class AsyncService {
    @Async("taskExecutor")
    public Future<Task> startAsyncProcess(Task task) {
        Thread threadToInterruptOnCancel = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Some continuous async db write"));
        threadToInterruptOnCancel.start();

        return new CancelWithRunnableFuture(
                       AsyncResult.forValue(task),
                       () -> threadToKillOnCancel.interrupt());
    }
}

class CancelWithRunnableFuture<V> implements Future<V> {
    private Future<V> delegate;
    private Runnable runOnCancel;

    public CancelWithRunnableFuture(Future<V> delegate, Runnable runOnCancel) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.runOnCancel = runOnCancel;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
        //
        // The Runnable is run here!
        //
        runOnCancel.run();

        return delegate.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCancelled() {
        return delegate.isCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDone() {
        return delegate.isDone();
    }

    @Override
    public V get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        return delegate.get();
    }

    @Override
    public V get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        return delegate.get(timeout, unit);
    }

}
```

Comment: Good way, but what if I will have a structure with other nested threads. Your way is pretty fine if I will have only one level of thread nesting. I mean It will be unsupportable in case of increasing of new threads and their locations across code or other tied services. I think I need some thread tree structure with thread dependencies like **parent -> child**. And when the **parent** is interrupted, a **child** should be interrupted in the chain as well.

Comment: So you could (a) create a type to encapsulate the parent/child(/grandchild) relationship of threads (it might just be as simple as a set of Threads that you need to maintain per task), (b) provision that type to propagate interrupt() calls to every Thread it knows about and (c) when Future.cancel() is called, have the Runnable call the method in (b).